# How can I use HTTP/1.x in client and server

Tags: http, go, https

I have a basic client and server implementations working using HTTP/2. I want to test that the server works with HTTP/1 too.

Is there any way to change the protocol from HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.x?

Client code:

```
func main() {
  host = "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
  client = http.Client{

    // InsecureTLSDial is temporary and will likely be
    // replaced by a different API later.
    Transport: &http2.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
  }

  // further functionality
}
```

Server code:

```
func main() {

    var srv http.Server
    srv.Addr = ":8080"

    // Set Routes
    routes()

    // Start server
    srv.ListenAndServeTLS("certs/localhost.cert", "certs/localhost.key")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the 2 methods listed at the start of the package documentation? https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: @JimB yes, TLSNextProto option is not working for me. I was able to make the server work in HTTP/1.x using GODEBUG but client is not working yet

Comment: Your client explicitly specifies a HTTP/2 transport even though that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution.

Change in the client

```
Transport: &http2.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
},
```

by

```
Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
```

Comment: `nil` is the zero value for slices, so these two code pieces produce the exact same value.